# Android: Draw on bitmap with finger in transparent color

Tags: android, draw

I have an ImageView with a bitmap. What I want: When the user draws with the finger on the bitmap this part should become transparent(set Pixel alpha value to 0) that you can see the views under the imageview.
Can I work with an ImageView or should I implement a custom view?

How can I realize this? (just roughly)

Comment: You could use an onTouch listener along with Bitmap.setPixel(int x, int y, int pixelColor), or even setPixels(int[] pixels, int offset, int stride, int x, int y, int width, int height), but this is going to be super slow. I don't think this is possible to do without lagging up if not crashing your application every time you touch the ImageView, aside from possibly using something like a SurfaceView.

Comment: You should 1) extend a View 2) override onDraw() 3) draw an image on its Canvas 4) create onTouchListener and handle onTouch events: remember what user has drawn by finger and invalidate View to handle it in onDraw()

Comment: Thanks I can now draw on the bitmap, but when I set the paint color to transparent it draws ON the bitmap transparent i.e. you do not see any stroke. But I want that the pixels of the bitmap become transparent. zgc7009's solution is too slow, as he already mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Canvas drawing. Create a custom view with mutable bitmap. 
Erasing can be achieved by setting Paint object like this:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

Implement drawing:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        if (w > 0 && h > 0) {


            // Set up canvas - bitmap can be initialized with your Image
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        if (mBitmap == null || mCanvas == null || mPath == null) {
            return;
        }
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
    }


    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);

            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }

    private void touchUp() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX + 1, mY + 1);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return true;
        }
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchUp();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to save the drawing?

Comment: You can save a bitmap, which is modified by canvas, or you can create classes for saving paths in a vector fashion - something like list of points.